# Win 10 Task Scheduler Start App Minimized/Task Mgr

Tags: windows-10

I do apologize in an advanced but I am not very PC tech here. I have found few topics here which describes the problem but because my app is different it throws me off.

I am looking to start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Corsair\CORSAIR iCUE Software\iCUE Launcher.exe" into the task bar with 5 seconds delay. I have accomplished the delay time thanks to this forum but I am unable to start the app directly into the task bar/minimized (I rather to be in the task bar and not minimized).
I am thinking I am trying commands associated with not win 10 version.

So far I got:

[image]

Thank you all in advance.

Thank you,
Niko

Comment: Have confirmed this software when minimized goes to the taskbar?